# Sin conexión por SSH al montar curlftpfs

Tags: debian, ssh

Se ha añadido una línea al **fstab** en un **debian 8.1** para automontar la conexión a un servidor FTP mediante curlftpfs

```
curlftpfs#myfetpserver.net /var/backups fuse  auto,allow_other,_netdev,ftp_port=- 0 0
```

Lo que sucede es que tras reiniciar el servidor, ya no se puede conectar via SSH por el puerto 22, se rechaza la conexión.

Si se monta la partición con el comando **mount -a**, no se obtiene error alguno. Y con **df -h** sale la particion y se tiene acceso.

Se ha comprobado el **iptables** y no se está bloqueando el acceso al puerto 22

**SOLUCIÓN:**

Dejar la linea del fstab de la siguiente forma:

```
myfetpserver.net /var/backups fuse.curlftpfs auto,allow_other,_netdev,ftp_port=- 0 0
```

Se necesitara tener instalado tanto fuse como curlftpfs. En debian o ubuntu son los siguientes comandos:

```
apt-get install fuse
apt-get install curlftpfs
```

Comment: Es probable que la conexión al servidor ssh se produzca porque el proceso de inicio del sistema se ha detenido intentando montar ese sistema de archivos. Si tienes acceso al equipo (físico o virtual) y puedes hacer un `ps -ef` es probable que veas el script de arranque que se ha quedado atascado y en `dmesg` cualquier error que se esté generando. ¿No tienes credenciales en el archivo `/etc/fstab`? Si estás usando un archivo `.netrc` para las credenciales es posible que no se esté usando durante el arranque, sólo sirve para el usuario que ejecuta el `mount -a`.

Comment: Una vez modificado el fichero fstab, reinicio el servidor para que aplique los cambios. Pero no puedo acceder por SSH, me toca iniciarlo en modo RESCUE para quitar la linea del fstab y poder iniciarlo en modo normal.

He probado usando el fichero .netrc y sin el fichero .netrc y en ambos casos ocurre lo mismo. 

Antes de reiniciar el servidor, uso el comando mount -a y se monta correctamente todo lo que hay en fstab (Incluido la conexión curlftps.

Por tanto, entiendo que el problema viene por bloqueo/uso de puertos, pero no doy con la tecla. En dmesg no hay error alguno (Log vacio)

Comment: No es un bloqueo de puertos. Es simplemente que tu servicio `sshd` ni tan siquiera llega a arrancar. El montaje se queda atascado preguntándote las credenciales. Cuando no usas el archivo `.netrc` ¿cómo le indicas las credenciales? El problema radica en que durante el arranque la variable de entorno `$HOME` no está definida ni ninguna otra.

Comment: Se hace con el siguiente patron:

curlftpfs#ftp://usuario:password@servidorftp.algo /punto/de/montaje fuse  allow_other 0 0

Comment: Procura cambiar a `myfetpserver.net /var/backups fuse.curlftpfs auto,allow_other,_netdev 0 0`, el subtipo de sistema de archivos lleva años y no se recomienda el antiguo en el que se usaba el prefijo. Voy a probar en una máquina virtual, pero en principio cuando me ha pasado esto ha sido por culpa de quedarse preguntando credenciales.

Comment: Ha funcionado!!

He dejado la linea del fstab de la siguiente forma:

myfetpserver.net /var/backups fuse.curlftpfs auto,allow_other,_netdev,ftp_port=- 0 0

Y ya puedo entrar por SSH

Comment: Enhorabuena! Te cedo la redacción de la respuesta. Luego te la editaré para incluir enlaces a documentación, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUCIÓN:**

He dejado la línea del archivo `fstab` de la siguiente forma:

```
myfetpserver.net /var/backups fuse.curlftpfs auto,allow_other,_netdev,ftp_port=- 0 0
```

Eliminando el prefijo `curlftpfs#` y agregando el indicador de subtipo de sistema de archivos `fuse.curlftpfs`.

Se necesitara tener instalado tanto fuse como curlftpfs. En debian o ubuntu son los siguientes comandos:

```
apt-get install fuse
apt-get install curlftpfs
```