# Servidor FTP montar diferentes carpetas

Tags: linux, servidor, ftp

Siguiendo los pasos indicados aquí [Sin conexión por SSH al montar curlftpfs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203406/sin-conexi%C3%B3n-por-ssh-al-montar-curlftpfs/203458#203458) he conseguido montar una partición en un servidor asociada a otro servidor FTP.

Pero sigo teniendo problemas a la hora de hacerlo en más de un directorio. Detallo la situación:

**Servidor FTP
/directorio_uno
/directorio_dos**

**Servidor Dedicado
/var/www/pagina_uno/backup
/var/www/pagina_dos/backup**

Lo que quiero es asociar */var/www/pagina_uno/backup* con */directorio_uno* y lo mismo  con */var/www/pagina_dos/backup* a */directorio_dos*

El problema viene que si construyo el CURLFTPS de la siguiente forma:

```
ftp://user_ftp:pass_ftp@server_ftp/directorio_uno /var/www/pagina_dos/backup fuse.curlftpfs auto,allow_other,_netdev,ftp_port=- 0 0
```

Me da el siguiente error al hacer el mount -a

**Error connecting to ftp: Server denied you to change to the given directory**

Comment: He creeado el directorio **directorio_uno** dentro del servidor FTP y dado permisos 777 y ya funciona el mount -a.

Pero lo que quiero es que no sea necesario crear la carpeta o hacerlo de forma automatica al ejecutarse el mount -a o mediante un script

Comment: puedes agregar esta linea de codigo en tu script $dir es  la varibale que contendra tu ruta if[[ ! -d $dir ]] && mkdir -p $dir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La idea para que funcione pasa por hacer un script que haga lo siguiente:

1. Se conecte por FTP al servidor
2. Una vez conectado haga un mkdir en el servidor
3. De los permisos a la nueva carpeta
4. Modifique el /etc/fstab del servidor dedicado
5. haga el mount -a

No consigo conectarme por ftp en una sola linea indicando host, user y pass.

**SOLUCIONADO:** Creando un script que se conecte y genere las carpetas usando EOF

```
apt-get install fuse -y
apt-get install curlftpfs -y    
apt-get install ftp -y
echo machine $BACKUPHOST login $BACKUPUSER password $BACKUPPASS >> ~/.netrc
chmod 600 ~/.netrc
mkdir -p $DIRWEB/backup

#AQUI NOS CONECTAMOS AL SERVIDOR DE BACKUPS Y CREAMOS EL DIRECTORIO#
ftp $BACKUPHOST << EOF
mkdir $DIRBACKUPS
chmod 777 $DIRBACKUPS
exit
EOF
```